# how to hidden the scrolling text word by word

Tags: html, ios, css, ionic-framework

I want to scroll the text, word by word, left to right. Just like this [page](http://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/scrolling-text.cfm), the word scrolling word by word until the last word. Then it will start again once the last word is hidden.

I am not use `<marquee>` for iOS because the scrolling text seems like not scrolling smooth like in Android. So, I did some changes in my [code](http://codepen.io/aishahismail/pen/YWypaR).

The result is the scrolling text was not hidden word by word until the last word. The last word not finish scrolling but suddenly it dissapear in a half way. Then it start srcolling again.

Comment: try -130px property of -100%

Comment: It worked when I put -230%. But if the character is less than the number of text in my code. It late to display the scrolling text again.

Answer (score 0):

try this css code

```
body {
cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

.scroll-left {
height: 50px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-left p {
white-space: nowrap !important;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
line-height: 50px;
/* Apply animation to this element */
-moz-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
-webkit-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
}
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  width:165%;
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
}
```

Comment: the code did hidden the scrolling text word by word but not untill the end of the word. it suddenly dissapear and start scrolling the text from the beginning